# MySQL where all in

Tags: mysql

I have five tables in my database, users, jobs, qualifications, job_qualifications and users_qualification

I need to select all the staff that are qualified to carry out a particular job.  It would be useful if there was a statement such as ALL IN so for example the query would be

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users_qualification
WHERE qualification_id ALL IN 
    (
        SELECT qualification_id 
        FROM job_qualifications 
        WHERE jobs_id = 1
    )
```

Comment: Just a thought: for your purpose, wouldn't it make more sense to do checking the other way around: select people where job qualifications are ALL IN user's qualifications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the number of qualifications that are required for the job, you can write this query:

```
SELECT uq.user_id
FROM users_qualification uq JOIN job_qualifications jq
    ON uq.qualification_id = jq.qualification_id
WHERE jq.jobs_id = 1
GROUP BY uq.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = {# of qualifications}
```

To find the number of qualifications, run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM job_qualifications
WHERE jq.jobs_id = 1
```

Comment: I need to ensure that I get users with the right qualifications, not just the same number of qualifications, will this still achieve that?

Comment: @bland-dan Yes, the `JOIN` takes care of that

Comment: Simple, elegant - AWESOME. I've been searching for hours, and this solved my problem in 10 seconds. Hats off to you, @TheScrumMeister.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on The Scrum Meister's answer, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    distinct uq.user_id
FROM
    users_qualification uq
    JOIN job_qualifications jq ON uq.qualification_id = jq.qualification_id
WHERE
    jq.jobs_id = 1
GROUP
    BY uq.user_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_qualifications jq2 WHERE jq2.job_id = jq.job_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexs +1 for enhancing scrumeister answer